# How to make sign up and login program in Python?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make a program that people can assign a username and password and then sign in. I was thinking about making two functions, one for sign up and one for login. However, it seems that it can't work because I assign a username in register part but when the sign in function runs it says that username is not defined. Do you have any idea what should I do?

```
def register():
    names=[]
    usernames=[]
    passwords=[]
    names.append(input("Enter your name:"))
    usernames.append(input("choose your username:"))
    passwords.append(input("choose your password:"))
    return usernames
def login(usernames,passwords):
    usernames=[]
    passwords=[]
    password=""
    username=""
    username=input("Enter your username:")
    password=input("Enter your Password:")
    if password==passwords[usernames.index(username)]:
       print("welcome")
    else:
       print("incorrect!")

account_ans=""
while True:
    account_ans=input("choose:  a)Sign Up     b)login and shop     c)quit")
    if account_ans=="a":
       register()
    if account_ans=="b":
       password=""
       username=""
       usernames=[]
       passwords=[]
       login(usernames,passwords)
    if account_ans=="c":break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `register()` function returns a list object `username` but you don't catch that into a variable so it's lost. All of that information you enter into `register()` disappears as soon as the function is done because of this.

So 1) Capture your return

```
if account_ans=="a":
   username=register()
```

When you get into the `account_ans="b"` portion of your code you then reset this `username` variable emptying it completely. So when you pass `username` to the `login()` function it's just an empty list. You can't log someone in that doesn't exist and so you get your error here.

So 2) Don't empty out your `username` list:

```
if account_ans=="b":
   login(usernames,passwords)
```

Of course there are more issues here, but those are the most glaring. I would suggest not passing your `username` and `password` lists around as it will get overwhelming try to juggle them through the spaghetti of code. Instead declare them at the top of your code and use them as globals. Daniel's answer on this same question shows a good way to pull this off.

Ultimately, the real problem here is your inability to debug the issue. A good starting point would be to toss some `print()` in there and see what's in these variables at different times in your code. You would see if you did a `print(usernames)` inside of your login function before the error pops that the `usernames` list is empty at this point in code execution. Then you can backtrack and figure out why `usernames` would be empty. You will hit a million errors like this as you are building out this code so learning how to debug now is going to be key to your success.

Comment: Check out Daniel's answer. The better option here is to declare your variables that will be used program-wide so they are "global". At that point you can manipulate them inside of functions and the rest of the flow of your program without passing them around as parameters. It will help unravel the spaghetti code you are headed towards.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
usernames = []
passwords = []
names = []


def register():
    names.append(input("Enter your name:"))
    usernames.append(input("choose your username:"))
    passwords.append(input("choose your password:"))


def login():
    username = input("Enter your username:")
    password = input("Enter your Password:")
    if username in usernames and password in passwords:
        print("welcome")
    else:
        print("incorrect!")


while True:
    account_ans = input("choose:  a)Sign Up     b)login and shop     c)quit ")
    if account_ans == "a":
        register()
    if account_ans == "b":
        login()
    if account_ans == "c":
        break
```

Comment: Thanks that was really Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the register function you can use the [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) function to get a list of inputs, then you can return the username and password variables. I also suggest using unique variable names just in case they override each other.

```
def register():
    names = input("Names: ").split(" ")
    username_list = input("Usernames: ").split(" ")
    password_list = input("Passwords: ").split(" ")

    return username_list, password_list
```

In the login function you can take inputs for the username and password then check it through the if condition. In this case you might have to [handle an exception](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_error_handling.asp) since if the user enters a wrong username you get a `ValueError` or alternatively you can just check both the username and the password from an if condition.

```
def login(usernames,passwords):
    username = input("Enter your username:")
    password = input("Enter your Password:")
    try:
        if password == passwords[usernames.index(username)]:
            print("welcome")
        else:
            print("incorrect!")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid username")
```

Here you can use the `elif` and `else` statements rather than only using `if` statements and when you call the register function you have to assign the values returned by it to 2 variables so you can use it in the login function.

```
while True:
    account_ans = input("choose:  a)Sign Up     b)login and shop     c)quit: ")
    if account_ans == "a":
       usernames, passwords = register()
       
    elif account_ans=="b":
       login(usernames,passwords)
       
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I didn't know about split function but now I searched and learned it. Thanks!